# NHibernate HasOne reference returning null

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, one-to-one

I'm using NHibernate and have a `Product` entity which can have 0 or 1 `ProductStats` entity.

**ProductMap**

```
References(x => x.Manufacturer);

HasOne(x => x.Stats)
            .PropertyRef(x => x.Product)
            .Cascade.All();
```

**ProductStatsMap**

```
References(x => x.Product);
```

**Database**

```
Product
 +ManufacturerId

ProductStats
 +ProductStatId
 +ProductId
```

I'm using the following query to try and load a list of products and their associated ProductStats if it exists.

```
var products = Session.Query<Product>()            // Using NHibernate.Linq
                      .Select(x => new
                      {
                          x.Manufacturer,          // Returns object correctly
                          x.Stats,                 // Returns null
                          x.Stats.ProductStatId    // Returns ID correctly
                       })
```

The `Stats` property always returns null, but if I try and query a property of `Stats`, it works fine, which indicates that the mapping itself is correct.  It just refuses to load the entire entity as part of this query.  The Manufacturer property which was mapped using `References` works fine.

Why is the Stats property not being loaded, and how can I resolve this?

Comment: I've encountered this a couple times as well.  I find that if I start the query from within the one-to-one relationship it seems to work around the problem.  So in the above if you started with `Session.Query<Stats>` instead and selected `Stats = x` it would work around this problem.